# How to use async / await in get request using vue + axios?

Tags: async-await, vuejs2, axios

I have the following code and would like to know how I can implement a try / catch with async / await executing the same function:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    skills: [],
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8080/wp-json/api/v1/skills')
      .then(response => {
        this.skills = response
      }).catch(err => (console.log(err)))
  }
})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

see code below:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  async mounted() {
    try{
      let response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/wp-json/api/v1/skills')
      this.skills = response
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```