# Upload image need to refresh using $emit / $on in Vue

Tags: vue.js, events, vuejs2, emit

I have a method that calls the user data via axios

```
// method name getUser()
const user = await axios.get(`/user/${this.id}`)
this.id = user.data.data.id
this.name = user.data.data.name
this.email = user.data.data.email
```

I then use that in the mounted so if user visits `/profile/id`
it'll load the user data

```
mounted() {
    this.getUser()
}
```

I tried to upload an image and I emit the event using global event bus once the image is successfully uploaded.

```
this.$event.$emit('IMAGE_UPLOAD')
```

Then catch that on the mounted too

```
mounted () {
// if I remove this it works, but I need to preload the data of the user
this.getUser()
this.$event.$on('IMAGE_UPLOAD', () => {
    this.getUser()
})
```

}

my problem is it doesn't change the image meaning I still need to refresh the page if I call the `this.getUser()` too inside the mounted.

So I'm wondering how to work around this.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use async / await in get request using vue + axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437420/how-to-use-async-await-in-get-request-using-vue-axios)

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate since the question is about how to get a work around on not to reload the page to see the changes on image upload.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your event handler is being called? Is it reloading the same image ID?

Comment: yes its being called. when I comment out the call on `this.getUser()` on mounted it works fine.

Comment: I need to have the data displayed upon the profile visit, then if user click the image a modal will popup where user can drag and drop image, then once done image should display the newly uploaded one.

Answer (score 0):

Since the url and name of the image does not change when the new image is uploaded the image in the browser is not updated. So what I have done in the past is a little trick to essentially change the url to the image by adding a unique query parameter. So use a data property for the location of your user image and in your method where you update the users data also update the img url and add something unique to the query parameter.  I usually use `new Date().getTime()`.  So you will end up with something like  `/img/user-xxxx.png?1559289852686`

```
data(){
   userImg: '/img/user-xxxx.png'
},
methods:{
   getUser(){
     //... get your user data
     .then((data)=>{
         this.userImg = data.user.img +'?'+ new Date().getTime();
     })
}
```